# How to deal with Activity and Fragment when returning to app after they're removed from memory?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having an issue of having two instances of the same fragment being attached to the activity. I have ActivityA attaching FragmentA on `onCreate`. When I leave the app while being on this Activity, browse other apps for a while, and return to the app, I see that the system is trying to re-create the activity. My log shows the code from the Fragment being ran TWICE. My guess is the Fragment is already attached but then the Activity attempts to create a new instance of FragmentA.

What happens to the Activity/Fragment when the system removes them from memory, and what's the best way to handle this? Any links would be helpful.

Will provide code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to check in your onCreate() method if your activity if being recreated from a previous state or not. I'm assuming you add your fragment on the onCreate() method of your activity. You can do something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        // Add the fragment here to your activity
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, new YourFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

By doing this, you are basically saying that if a previous state is not found, you add your fragment. Otherwise you automatically get back the fragment that already exists.